# How can I test if a string for a function call using regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I test with regex if a given string is a function call (in my case a JavaScript function)

Example Strings:

```
"myfunction(x,y);"
"myobject.myfunction(x,y);"
```

Comment: Does it need to be a valid function in your program? If so there isn't a way to tell the different between `"validFunction(x,y)"` and `"invalidFunction(x,y)"`.

Comment: `function a () {return 1}\n(function () {return 1})()` will have only one function call. I don't think regex is the right solution here. You should make your question more specific on what you want to search for.

Comment: I just want to test the string if it is a function call to path the string to the JavaScript eval function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(.+(, ?.+)*\);
```

Comment: Thanks - I use now the following simplified pattern ignoring the prefixed class name:   "^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+\("